# Why does Android's material button's 'onPressed' state actually rising up instead of getting pushed down?

Tags: google-material-design, button

So like this:

[image]

Why is this good? How is it decided to be like this way?

I'm an Android developer and no matter whom I show my apps with these default Android buttons, **everybody tells me I messed up because I mixed the pressed state.** Programers, designers, non professionals, no matter whom I ask, almost everyone has this opinion - However I did nothing, this is the standard method by the Android SDK.

Is it bad practice? Should I change it? Should I write my own button to work the opposite way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [Google Material design guide](https://material.io/guidelines/components/buttons.html#buttons-raised-buttons) they behave like this because they were designed to be an object resting on top of another, thus when you "press" it the button actually raises from its place towards the user. In reality the button doesn't move at all - the shadow under the button slides towards the bottom of the screen, providing visual feedback to the user. You can see [some buttons in action here](https://www.muicss.com/docs/v1/css-js/buttons) (it's made with CSS but it should behave like the android ones).

It goes against the previous standard where digital buttons should behave like a physical button being depressed, which is why you're getting so many negative reviews on it.

In the end it's up to you if you want to keep it or change, the default styles are there to provide working elements and the guidelines are not laws. Do what you believe is going to provide the best experience for your users.

Answer (score 0):

Well,from what I could figure out and from an UX point of view it's a little better when you press the button for it to rise[**1**] because at that point your finger isn't covering the button completely and you are reassured that you have pressed the right button + **it's not giving you the feeling that it's sliding out of your reach**.

- If it were to stay where it is you wouldn't get any visual feedback
  that it's working and you actually pressed it.
- If it goes down, your finger will cover even more the button and it
  will feel like it's sliding out of your finger's reach.

[**1**] *this needed to be changed and applied to touchscreen devices opposed to when using a mouse since your finger is a lot bigger than a small cursor + your finger is attached to your had [:))] and it sometimes gets in the way as well*